# How to enforce tslint rules before merging/push/commit git commands

Tags: angular, git, azure-devops, tslint, azure-repos

I have a web app running in Azure DevOps and want to ensure the code is up to standards before merging; for example to "dev/test/master". I have made a tslint rule file and would like to enforce this rule. Enforce it in a way that, whenever theirs a pull request to a branch. When approved or before it gets approved make the build fail. Or even better, don't let the developer make a pull request until his code matches tslint rules.

Is there any tool I can integrate to azure pipelines to check code and compare it with tslint rules so whenever it doesn't match, make the merge or build fail.

Comment: I have only tried tslint before commits, but not before any PRs. Is that applicable to your case too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) pre-commit hook.

Git Hooks that work with Husky framework. [git-scm.com/docs/githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Install husky and add below code in your package.json. It'll not allow committing the code if tslint rule or build fails.

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --prod"
  },
 "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run build"
    }
  },
```

Comment: It was actually that simple. Just npm install husky and add those lines to the package.json and it will work. Thanks Rahul

Comment: Here are the Git Hooks that work with Husky framework. https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks